# Run button click event only once further clicks needs to be forwarded to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

and I have 2 functions

```
function event1(){
  alert("1st Time Clicked");
}

function event2(){
  alert("Further Clicks");
}
```

I want to run `event1` function for 1st time when the user clicks on that button and for subsequent requests I need to run `event2` function.

I tried the following way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").one("click",function(){
        event1();
    });
});
```

But I can't figure it out how to run `event2` function for further clicks.

How Can I do that in Jquery ?

I created Jsfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevgurram/d9Z3c/

Answer (score 3):

In the first click handler(using .one()), register a normal click handler so that further clicks will trigger that handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").one("click", function () {
        event1();
        $(this).click(event2)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3MJ82/)

Answer (score 0):

I like booleans so I use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false;

    $("#btn").on("click",function(){
        if(!clicked) {
            event1();
            clicked = true;
        } else {
            event2();   
        }
    });
});
```

P.S. I just wanted to be different from the first answer. XD